# RegOpenKeyEx returns 2 when accessing wow6432node

Tags: vb.net

I try to read all Uninstall keys from the registry using VB.net 2010.
As I want to know the modify date of the key, I have to use advapi32.DLL functions.
On the my local System the key and modify Dates can be read, on the remote registry too but not if the key is located under the wow6432node. Althought I set the KEY_QUERY_VALUE to KEY_WOW64_32KEY.

Here's my code:

```
Dim SubKey as String = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
Dim hRemoteKey As IntPtr
Dim regkeyptr As Integer = RegConnectRegistry(tbServername.Text, New IntPtr(RegistryHive.LocalMachine), hRemoteKey)

Dim KEY_QUERY_VALUE as Integer = 1 + 512

Dim openregkeyResult As Integer = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, SubKey, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, regkeyptr)
Dim lpftLastWriteTime As System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME
Dim returnvalue As Integer = RegQueryInfoKey( _
regkeyptr, _
Nothing, _
Nothing, _
Nothing, _
Nothing, _
Nothing, _
Nothing, _
Nothing, _
Nothing, _
Nothing, _
Nothing, _
lpftLastWriteTime)
```